# how to have a picture in a picture-box change every 10 seconds

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am making a CCTV camera sort of thing and I want the pictures in the picture-boxes to change every ten seconds can someone please help me. i have tried using

```
pic1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Documents and Settings\IT\My Documents\Downloads\whitehouse 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
pic1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Documents and Settings\IT\My Documents\Downloads\penatagon")
```

Comment: Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer control and update image on Timer.Tick event. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:
If these images aren't too big and plentiful you should consider preloading them all beforehand:

```
Dim images As New List(Of Image)()
images.add(Image.FromFile(Somefilepath))
images.add(Image.FromFile(your2ndFilepath))
' etc.
```

Now create a Timer that will tick every 10 seconds:

```
Dim pictureChangeTimer As New Timer()
'Creates a timer
AddHandler pictureChangeTimer.Tick, AddressOf pictureChangeTimer_tick
'creates an event handler, simply type in pictureChangeTimer.Tick += and hit tab twice. this will automatically create the method for you
' Sets the timer interval to 10 seconds.
pictureChangeTimer.Interval = 10000
pictureChangeTimer.Start()
```

Now in a separate function you can change your pictures every time the event launches:

```
Private Sub pictureChangeTimer_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'if using a list
    index = (index + 1) Mod images.Count()
    pic1.Image = images(index)
    'using your original example
    'pic1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Documents and Settings\IT\My Documents\Downloads\whitehouse.jpg")
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that repeated uses of `Image.FromFile` may result in an exception against the same file, if the previous reference still exists/hasn't been disposed as it maintains an open handle to the file. As it stands this answer's code needs some work to make sense - the Index variable is never modified nor declared, and the FromFile version uses a hardcoded path, so the timer tick will always display the same image regardless of how many times it ticks. Future users of this answer's code will need to do quite a bit more work on it

Comment: ps; the commented advice *"simply type in pictureChangeTimer.Tick += and hit tab twice"* is wrong for VB.NET - that's a C# way of attaching an event handler programmatically. VB declares the variable WithEvents and can then use `Sub NameOfSubThatHandles Handles timer.Tick` or it uses `AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf NameOfSubThatHandles` styles. The C# handler add shortcut (tab tab) does not apply to VB