# How do you delay the code to change an image to another, then back

Tags: vb.net, delay

I'm trying to change an image in a picture box after 10 - 20 seconds of the form starting, to a gif for about 2 seconds, then back to the original image, then loop. I'm struggling with how to write it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer to [how to have a picture in a picture-box change every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156391/how-to-have-a-picture-in-a-picture-box-change-every-10-seconds) shows how to use a timer to change an image. You can change the `.Interval` of a timer if you need to, and use `.Stop()` to stop a timer.

Comment: I have checked that post and wrote it but it says the 'myTimer' parts are not declared. and also 'images(index)' is not declared. do i need to put a timer on the form?

Comment: It looks like the author of that answer got their `pictureChangeTimer` and `myTimer` names mixed up. You can put a timer on the form (it will be named Timer1 by default) or you can put `Private Shared WithEvents myTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()` just after the `Public Class Form1` line in the code. Where it says `images.add(Image.FromFile(Somefilepath))`, change that to add the first image you want, then repeat the line with the second image.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it is now saying the `AddressOf myTimer_tick` is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level (the myTimer_tick part)

Comment: Even though that other answer has issues, I'd say that it has enough of the barebones of the idea that it's usable enough to mark this Q as a duplicate of that Q

Comment: @JoelBasile is the Sub in the same class as the AddressOf statement? Does your code contain a Sub with that exact name? If you write code that progresses the state of your program beyond what it was when you first ask a question, always, always, *always*, edit your question saying exactly what you have done, why, what the code looks like now, what the exact error message it throws is, and on which line it occurs. Do *not* write reams of code in comments; edit the question

Comment: And if someone has already posted an answer to your question, do *not* edit the question so that the answer loses context or becomes irrelevant; ask a new question

Comment: @JoelBasile I have updated the answer I referred to previously, but I also added an answer here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to have a picture in a picture-box change every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156391/how-to-have-a-picture-in-a-picture-box-change-every-10-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I would load the GIF as a Resource: Project --> Properties --> Resources --> Add

Then use code like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ShowGif As Boolean = False
    Private WithEvents tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds
        tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick
        ShowGif = Not ShowGif
        If ShowGif Then
            ' switch to two seconds
            tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds

            ' save the current image in the tag
            If IsNothing(PictureBox1.Tag) Then
                PictureBox1.Tag = PictureBox1.Image
            End If

            ' load the GIF
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.something ' <- change to your resource name
        Else
            ' switch back to ten seconds
            tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds

            ' restore the original image
            PictureBox1.Image = PictureBox1.Tag
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) to generate tick events at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

As you have varying times for the different images, you could create a class to hold the image's filename and how long it is to be shown for - this will make it simpler to decide what to set the timer's interval to when the image is changed. It might look like a lot of typing, but it is worth it to keeps things simple.

Then you can create a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) of that class so that you can have as many instances of it as you need that are easily referred to.

For example, I put a PictureBox on a Form and added this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim imageTimer As Timer
    Dim timedImages As List(Of TimedImage)
    Dim timedImageIndex As Integer

    Class TimedImage
        Public Property Filename As String
        Public Property Duration As Integer

        Public Sub New()
            ' Empty constructor
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(filename As String, duration As Integer)
            Me.Filename = filename
            Me.Duration = duration
        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Sub TimedImageChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        timedImageIndex = (timedImageIndex + 1) Mod timedImages.Count
        ' Dispose of the previous image (if any) to avoid a memory leak:
        PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(timedImages(timedImageIndex).Filename)
        imageTimer.Interval = timedImages(timedImageIndex).Duration

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitTimedImages()

        timedImages = New List(Of TimedImage)
        timedImages.Add(New TimedImage("C:\Temp\sprites\1\IM1.jpg", 1000))
        timedImages.Add(New TimedImage("C:\Temp\sprites\1\IM2.jpg", 3000))

        ' Call the image change handler immediately so it can set itself up with the first image and interval:
        imageTimer = New Timer With {.Interval = 1}
        timedImageIndex = timedImages.Count - 1
        AddHandler imageTimer.Tick, AddressOf TimedImageChange
        imageTimer.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitTimedImages()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' Tidy up.
        If imageTimer IsNot Nothing Then
            imageTimer.Stop()
            imageTimer.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

and it alternated the image between the two pictures I specified in the `InitTimedImages()` method.